# how to Viewport mimic?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am using two viewports, one with a render display filter, one displaying solid for editing. I want the viewport of the render view to mimic the rotations of my view that I'm editing in. Is there a way to parent my views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a camera view. The perspective "camera" is not accessible.

1. Create a camera.
2. Set both views to that camera.
3. In the editing viewport press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel, then check [Lock Camera to View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#view-panel).

When you manipulate the view in the viewport, you will not exit the camera, but change its transformation.

Comment: Thanks, for the work around. It works but the rendering border is a little annoying to look at

Comment: @MrTom You an zoom in before locking the camera to view.